# ResourceAware instead of MultiResourceItemReader.getCurrentResource() for LineCallbackHandlers

Tags: spring-batch

I am using a `MultiResourceItemReader` which has recently had it's `getCurrentResource()` method deprecated (See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3776).

The replacement is to use `ResourceAware` interface but I am facing an issue and wondering if anyone can help.

Current setup:

- I have a `MultiResourceItemReader` that uses a `FlatFileItemReader` delegate
- The `FlatFileItemReader` utilises a `LineCallbackHandler` that is set up using the `FlatFileItemReaderBuilder`'s `skippedLinesCallback()` method
- Current implementation has the `MultiResourceItemReader` injected into the `LineCallbackHandler` so that the `handleLine(String line)` method can make use of knowing which file is currently being processed
- As I understand it, the `ResouceAware` interface is implemented on domain items but in my case I don't have an instance of an domain item yet... I just have the input String from the file because the line has been skipped

**How would I go about making my LineCallbackHandler "resource aware" so that I can continue with the logic I have just now?**

Code:

Config:

```
  @Bean
  public MultiResourceItemReader<Items> reader(@Value(SPRING_VALUE_TO_LOOK_FOR) final String paths) {
    final Resource[] resources = EtlHelpers.convertFilesToProcessFromContextString(paths);
    final MultiResourceItemReader<Items> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    reader.setName("multiFileReader");
    reader.setDelegate(fileReaderDelegate());
    reader.setResources(resources);
    return reader;
  }

  @Bean
  public FlatFileItemReader<Items> fileReaderDelegate() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Items>()
        .name("fileReader")
        .linesToSkip(1)
        .skippedLinesCallback(headerValidator)
              // (extra unrelated config)
        .build();
  }
```

LineCallbackHandler named `HeaderValidator`

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HeaderValidator implements LineCallbackHandler {
    private final MultiResourceItemReader<Items> itemReader;

    @Override
    public void handleLine(@NonNull final String line) {
        final String desc = Optional.ofNullable(itemReader.getCurrentResource()).map(Resource::getDescription).orElse("file");
        log.info("{}: Ensuring headings are on the first line and are correct (using case-insensitive comparisons)", desc);
        // ... other uses of itemReader.getCurrentResource() omitted for brevity 
    }
}
```

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thanks that helped. I have raised a new Feature request: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3883    (sorry just not had time to raise it till now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to skip headers and know from which resource each header comes from. Even though this is very specific use case, I think it is a valid one since it could be applied to any line considered as comment (like knowing the source file of each comment line).

> Current implementation has the MultiResourceItemReader injected into the LineCallbackHandler so that the handleLine(String line) method can make use of knowing which file is currently being processed

I hope you agree that this couples the `LineCallbackHandler` to the `MultiResourceItemReader` which is not ideal (as explained in the [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3776) that deprecates `MultiResourceItemReader#getCurrentResource`). If this coupling is not an issue for you, then you can get the current resource from the `FlatFileItemReader` itself, since the `MultiResourceItemReader` [sets the current resource on the delegate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/f6a8d105950fbbc3cd557b591dded85329278f15/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.java#L133) each time a new resource is processed. You can find a complete example [here](https://github.com/benas/spring-batch-lab/tree/master/issues/so66908987) (note that this requires a new getter for the resource in `FlatFileItemReader`).

That said, I see no obvious way to implement your use case with what is currently offered by Spring Batch. The `skippedLinesCallback` is called in the `doOpen` method, which is earlier than mapping items where the resource is set via `ResourceAware`. The most straightforward way that comes to my mind to address such use case is by having a `ResourceAwareLineCallbackHandler` and make the `FlatFileItemReader` set the current resource on it.

Please open an issue with a reference to this SO question and we can discuss the best way to introduce this feature. Thank you upfront.

Comment: For reference the newly raised issue is available at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3883